# Printing a column from a .txt file

Tags: python, txt

I'm a beginner at Python.

I'm having trouble printing the values from a .txt file.

```
  NFL_teams = csv.DictReader(txt_file, delimiter = "\t")
  print(type(NFL_teams))
  columns = NFL_teams.fieldnames
  print('Columns: {0}'.format(columns))
  print(columns[2])
```

This gets me to the name of the 3rd column ("team_id") but I can't seem to print any of the data that would be in the corresponding column. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The .txt file looks like this:

```
team_name   team_name_short team_id team_id_pfr team_conference team_division   team_conference_pre2002 team_division_pre2002   first_year  last_year
Arizona Cardinals   Cardinals   ARI CRD NFC NFC West    NFC NFC West    1994    2021
Phoenix Cardinals   Cardinals   ARI CRD NFC -   NFC NFC East    1988    1993
St. Louis Cardinals Cardinals   ARI ARI NFC -   NFC NFC East    1966    1987
Atlanta Falcons Falcons ATL ATL NFC NFC South   NFC NFC West    1966    2021
Baltimore Ravens    Ravens  BAL RAV AFC AFC North   AFC AFC Central 1996    2021
Buffalo Bills   Bills   BUF BUF AFC AFC East    AFC AFC East    1966    2021
Carolina Panthers   Panthers    CAR CAR NFC NFC South   NFC NFC West    1995    2021
```

There are tabs between each item.

Comment: Can you share an example of what the file looks like that you're trying to read?

Comment: Try `for row in NFL_teams: print(row)`.